# Ops with ImportHelper, Possible option to decide whether to open the File Browser window?

Tags: python, operator

When the ImportHelper helper class is inserted into an operator by default, the operator opens a popup with the File Browser window.

Now the question is this, I would like to keep an operator who works in 2 ways, 1 is the one in which a Browser opens for me and the other, is the one that does not open a browser and executes my code.

I'll give an example to explain even better:

```
class ImportSomeData(Operator, ImportHelper):
    
    bl_idname = "import.test"
    bl_label = "Import Some Data"

    open_file_browser: BoolProperty(default=True)
    file: StringProperty()
    
    filter_glob: StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'}, default='*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp')

    def execute(self, context):
        if self.open_file_browser:
            # Choose file from File Browser:
            my_file = self.filepath
        else:
            # Choose the file from a known path: 
            my_file = self.file
        
        if os.path.isfile(my_file):
            bpy.data.images.load(my_file)
            
        return {'FINISHED'}
    

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        
        layout = self.layout
        
        # Button 1:
        # Import file from File Browser:
        ops = layout.operator("import.test", text="Load")
        ops.open_file_browser = True
        
        # Button 2        
        # Import file from a known path:
        ops = layout.operator("import.test", text="Load")
        ops.open_file_browser = True
        ops.file = "c:\\my_file_path\\my_file.jpg"
```

Comment: By the time the code reaches `execute` it's already too late, the file browser is open. You have to use the `invoke` method and switch there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gorgious stated, the `invoke` method is the place to make the switch: open the file browser or not?
But when you call the `execute` method in the `invoke` method, the file browser isn't opened automatically, so the extra trick is to bind the file selector within the invoke a second time with `context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)` (see [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add)).

Entire code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, StringProperty
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
import os


class ImportSomeData(Operator, ImportHelper):
    
    bl_idname = "import.test"
    bl_label = "Import Some Data"

    open_file_browser: BoolProperty(default=True, options={'HIDDEN'})
    file: StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'})
    
    filter_glob: StringProperty(options={'HIDDEN'}, default='*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp')
    
    
    # Operator is called, but not executed yet
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        # Choose image file in File browser?
        if self.open_file_browser:
            # Open File browser
            # See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add
            context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            # Do not open File browser, perform operator immediately
            return self.perform_operator()
    
    
    # User has selected an image in the File browser
    def execute(self, context):
        self.file = self.filepath
        return self.perform_operator()
    
    
    # Perform operator: load image
    def perform_operator(self):
        if os.path.isfile(self.file):
            bpy.data.images.load(self.file)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        
        layout = self.layout
        
        # Button 1:
        # Import file from File Browser:
        ops = layout.operator("import.test", text="Load")
        ops.open_file_browser = True
        
        # Button 2        
        # Import file from a known path:
        ops = layout.operator("import.test", text="Load")
        ops.open_file_browser = False
        ops.file = "c:\\my_file_path\\my_file.jpg"


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ImportSomeData)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ImportSomeData)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: This is the solution, work fine 